# getElementById returns null when element in interlaced <div> tags

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I know this question was asked many times before, however, I never could find this specific setup.

My script is located at the end of the `<body>` tag and I am executing an alert message with `window.onload`, so the reason can't be the DOM not having loaded yet.

It is also not a typo or anything, as I cut&paste the same code passage for testing purposes and when not having an interlaced `<div>` it works just fine.

However, when I put the `<div>` inside another `<div>` the return value suddenly changes to null.

I can't really comprehend that behavior.

Here's two code examples to illustrate the issue better:

Working:

```
<div id="test123"></div>

// returns the div object

window.onload = function() {
alert(document.getElementById("info123"));
};
```

Not working:

```
<div id ="charts_container" style="bottom:0px;padding:0px;overflow:auto;position:absolute; top:35px; left:0px; right:0px; background-color:#ffffff;margin-right:0px;" >
    <div id="test123"></div>
</div>

// returns null

window.onload = function() {
alert(document.getElementById("test123"));
};
```

Comment: hopefully the script is inside `<script></script>` tags...

Comment: I guess AmCharts removes the original HTML from `#charts_container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither example will work. `info123` is not `test123`. You need to use the right id!

[Putting an element inside another one will not hide it from the DOM](http://jsbin.com/wehaqido/1/edit). Either:

1. You made an error, such as leaving off the `>` from the previous tag (use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org)) *or*
2. You have some other JavaScript that is removing the element before you try to find it

Comment: Just wrote that as an example, it's not like that in the code. Corrected mistake in OP